# Error plotting a function of 2 variables

Tags: function, matlab

I am trying to plot the function

```
f(x, y) = (x – 3).^2 – (y – 2).^2.
```

x is a vector from 2 to 4,  and y is a vector from 1 to 3, both with increments of 0.2. However, I am getting the error:

> "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals".

What do I do to fix this error?

Comment: If you  want help with Matlab code, post Matlab code, not some approximation to it.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I (think) I see what you are trying to achieve. You are writing your syntax like a mathematical function definition. Matlab is interpreting `f` as a 2-dimensional data type and trying to assign the value of the expression to data indexed at `x,y`. The values of `x` and `y` are not integers, so Matlab complains.

If you want to plot the output of the function (we'll call it `z`) as a function of `x` and `y`, you need to define the function quite differently . . .

```
f = @(x,y)(x-3).^2 - (y-2).^2;
x=2:.2:4;
y=1:.2:3; 
z = f(  repmat(x(:)',numel(y),1)  , repmat(y(:),1,numel(x) ) );

surf(x,y,z); 
xlabel('X'); ylabel('Y'); zlabel('Z');
```

This will give you an output like this . . . 
[image]

The `f = @(x,y)` part of the first line states you want to define a function called `f` taking variables `x` and `y`. The rest of the line is the definition of that function.

If you want to plot `z` as a function of both `x` and `y`, then you need to supply all possible combinations in your range. This is what the line containing the `repmat` commands is for.

**EDIT**

There is a neat Matlab function `meshgrid` that can replace the repmat version of the script as suggested by @bas (welcome bas, please scroll to bas' answer and +1 it!) ...

```
f = @(x,y)(x-3).^2 - (y-2).^2;
x=2:.2:4;
y=1:.2:3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
surf(x,y,f(X,Y)); 
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

Answer (score 2):

I typically use the [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) function. Like so:

```
x = 2:0.2:4;
y = 1:0.2:3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
F = (X-3).^2-(Y-2).^2;
surf(x,y,F);
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('f')
```

This is identical to the answer by @learnvst. it just does the repmat-ing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the function you are using uses integers, and you are trying to assign a double to it. Integers cannot have decimal places. To fix this, you can make it to where it increases in increments of 1, instead of 0.2